# How can I disable the certificate/SSL handshake on the 'www' version of my site served by Apache?

Tags: htaccess, apache, https, httpd.conf

We use SSL on the `https://www` version of our website.

Now I would like to disable the SSL connection on the `https://non-www` version of our website, so the result is:

- `https://non-www` => SSL handshake
- `https://www =>` no SSL

Can this be done?

Comment: By "disable" I assume you mean that it should not be accessible, not redirect to something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# if https and starts with www, go to http version
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if not https and it doesnt start with www, go to https version
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```